# Where do I go to change the position of the style.css?

Tags: css

My CSS style.css file is in my theme folder. I would like to put it in a CDN. How do I change the link element that loads the css?

I am using as a base the 2013 wordpress theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to themes functions.php file. Replace '`http://cdn.something.com/something.css`' to your stylesheet file uri on CDN.

```
add_filter('stylesheet_uri', 'my_custom_stylesheet_location');
function my_custom_stylesheet_location( $stylesheet_uri ){
    return 'http://cdn.something.com/something.css';
}
```

Comment: I put it in the function.php?

Comment: Yes, just replace the `http://cdn.something.com/something.css` with your stylesheet file uri on CDN.